# How to write to a file the Contents of Object response header in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

The response and request objects are the callback arguments to the asynchronous function http.createServer. I am trying to write to a file the Contents of response (res Object) header.

I am using JSON.stringify(res,null,4) which presents the output in more readable format but its throwing error "TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON". Please let know what i am missing here.

```
http.createServer(function(req,res) {
    const fileInput=JSON.stringify(res,null,4);

    fs.watch('testdir', function(eventType,fileName) {
            console.log(`event type is: ${eventType}`); 
            if (fileName) {
                    console.log(`FILENAME PROVIDED:- ${fileName}`);
                } else {
                    console.log(`FILENAME NOT PROVIDED`);
                }
            });

    fs.writeFile('testdir/response_object.txt',  fileInput, function(err,data) {
        if (err) {
            res.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type':'text/html'});
            return res.end('404 ERROR OCCURED WHILE WRITING TO THE FILE');
        } else {
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/html'});
            return res.end('FILE WRITE SUCCESSFUL');
        }
    });
}).listen(8080);
```

Comment: The `res` object is a native object, not supposed to be stringified. If you want to learn more about it, read [the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse). Or what exactly do you want to write to that file, the HTTP message body?

Comment: Like response object, request object has properties for the request query string, parameters, body, http headers and lots of other valuable information. I can see the output when i dump it using console.dir(res) but since the output is quite huge. I am writing it to the file. Basically I need to see the whole output of res object. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You can `util.inspect()` it and write that to a file. Or simply `console.log()` it and redirect the process output to a file.

Comment: "*The whole output*" - no you cannot output the whole object, it has circular references and is pretty large. If you want to inspect it out of curiosity on arbitrary levels, use a debugger instead.

Comment: Perfect. util.inspect() did the trick. Appreciate it :)